# Drag and drop shapes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rectangle shape in a stackpanel and i want to drag and drop in a grid with the mouse using WPF!
I appreciate it if someone can help me?
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet and have some code to share that has issues or is it that you don't know where to begin? If its the latter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx

Answer (score 9):

A very simple implementation follows.  It simply handles the Mouse button down/up/move events of the `Rectangle` in order to position it along with mouse movement.  There is no error checking and nothing to prevent the user from dragging the rectangle off of the Canvas and leaving it there.

XAML:

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="canvas">
            <Rectangle
                Name="rect"
                Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Canvas.Left="0"
                Canvas.Top="0"
                Fill="Red"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="rect_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                MouseLeftButtonUp="rect_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                MouseMove="rect_MouseMove"
                />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _isRectDragInProg;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rect_MouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            _isRectDragInProg = true;
            rect.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void rect_MouseLeftButtonUp( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            _isRectDragInProg = false;
            rect.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void rect_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            if( !_isRectDragInProg ) return;

            // get the position of the mouse relative to the Canvas
            var mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

            // center the rect on the mouse
            double left = mousePos.X - (rect.ActualWidth / 2);
            double top = mousePos.Y - (rect.ActualHeight / 2);
            Canvas.SetLeft( rect, left );
            Canvas.SetTop( rect, top );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For implementing drag and drop in an items control where the items are laid out by anything other than a canvas, then I would highly recommend checking out [Bea Stollnitz solution](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53). This is a completely reusable solution to drag and drop between any items control using attached properties.

**Update:** given that Bea's blog is gone, there are other posts that are based on her solution still available:

1. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF
2. [http://blogarchive.claritycon.com/blog/2009/03/generic-wpf-drag-and-drop-adorner](http://blogarchive.claritycon.com/blog/2009/03/generic-wpf-drag-and-drop-adorner/)
3. [https://siderite.dev/blog/mvvm-drag-and-drop.html](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/01/mvvm-drag-and-drop-part-1.html)

Comment: Link broken. Any recollection of the solution?

Comment: There are a few others that reference her work. https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2009/03/generic-wpf-drag-and-drop-adorner/

Comment: reference 2 and 3 did not work anymore, please update your post

Answer (score 0):

Extending what @Ed S answered.The problem with using a Canvas is you can basically drag the controls beyond the boundaries. If you want to make sure it won't cross the boundaries, I created a simple application where if you have two shapes you can either move both of them together or drag individually. Ofcourse I have a checkbox with name ChkDual mode to decide if shapes have to move together or not. You can edit that functionality as you need.

```
<Grid>
<!--Set some height and width as you like-->
     <Canvas x:Name="CnvBarCodeImage" AllowDrop="True">

                                </Canvas>
<Grid>

private void CreateUIShapes(int numberOfWindows)
        {
//If you want multiple shapes put it inside a loop
                Thumb th = null;
                th = new Thumb();
                th.Width = 200;
                th.Height = 100;
                th.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
                th.BorderBrush = Colors.Green;
                th.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);

                th.DragDelta += (sender, e) => Th_DragDelta(sender, e);
                Canvas.SetLeft(th, 100);
                Canvas.SetTop(th, 80);
               CnvBarCodeImage.Children.Add(th);

        }

 private event Action<Thumb, double, double> ChangeDimensions;
 private void Th_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e, List<Dimensions> limitedWindowMovements)
        {
            var selectedDraggableThumb = sender as Thumb;
            double left = (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) >= 0) ? Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) : 0;
            double top = (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) >= 0) ? Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) : 0;

            if (ChkDualMode.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var otherDraggableThumbs = CnvBarCodeImage.Children.OfType<Thumb>().Where(x => x != selectedDraggableThumb).ToList();
                var maxTopSelected = 0

                var maxLeftSelected = 0;

                //There may be n number of windows.
                foreach (var item in otherDraggableThumbs)
                {
                    //TOP
                    //Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) <= 0 || Canvas.GetTop(item) <= 0 original.
                    if (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) <= maxTopSelected || Canvas.GetTop(item) <= maxTopSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.VerticalChange <= 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    //LEFT
                    //Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) <= 0 || Canvas.GetLeft(item) <= 0 original.
                    else if (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) <= maxLeftSelected || Canvas.GetLeft(item) <= maxLeftSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.HorizontalChange <= 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    //RIGHT
                    else if (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) >=
                        CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth - selectedDraggableThumb.ActualWidth ||
                        Canvas.GetLeft(item) >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth - item.ActualWidth)
                    //|| Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) >= maxRightSelected
                    //|| Canvas.GetLeft(item) >= maxRightSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.HorizontalChange > 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }


                    //BOTTOM
                    else if (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) + selectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight ||
                            Canvas.GetTop(item) + item.ActualHeight >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight)
                    {
                        if (e.VerticalChange >= 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    if (ChangeDimensions == null)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions += BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                    }

                }

                foreach (var item in otherDraggableThumbs)
                {
                    ChangeDimensions?.Invoke(item, e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);
                }

                left = (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth) ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth : left;
                top = (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight) ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight : top;
                Canvas.SetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb, left + e.HorizontalChange);
                Canvas.SetTop(selectedDraggableThumb, top + e.VerticalChange);
            }
            else
            {
                //In single mode limit the movement as well.
                int.TryParse(selectedDraggableThumb.Name, out var indexFromName);
                var limitedDimensionForWindow = limitedWindowMovements[indexFromName];

                var maxTop = limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxTopPossible == null ? 0 : limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxTopPossible;
                var maxLeft = limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxLeftPossible == null ? 0 : limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxLeftPossible;
                var maxRight = limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxRightPossible == null ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth - selectedDraggableThumb.ActualWidth : limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxRightPossible;
                var maxBottom = limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxBottomPossible == null ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight - selectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight : limitedDimensionForWindow.MaxBottomPossible;

                if (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) <= maxTop)
                {
                    if (e.VerticalChange <= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) <= maxLeft)
                {
                    if (e.HorizontalChange <= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) >= maxRight)
                {
                    if (e.HorizontalChange >= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) >= maxBottom)
                {
                    if (e.VerticalChange >= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                left = (Canvas.GetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb) >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth) ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualWidth : left;
                top = (Canvas.GetTop(selectedDraggableThumb) >= CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight) ? CnvBarCodeImage.ActualHeight : top;
                Canvas.SetLeft(selectedDraggableThumb, left + e.HorizontalChange);
                Canvas.SetTop(selectedDraggableThumb, top + e.VerticalChange);
            }
        }

        private void BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions(Thumb sender, double arg1, double arg2)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                double left = (Canvas.GetLeft(sender) > 0) ? Canvas.GetLeft(sender) : 0;
                double top = (Canvas.GetTop(sender) > 0) ? Canvas.GetTop(sender) : 0;
                Canvas.SetLeft(sender, left + arg1);
                Canvas.SetTop(sender, top + arg2);
            }
        }
```