# Sortable WrapPanel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement [this functionality in wpf.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid)
  when you go to that link note how you can drag objects around and place them on a different location. I was wondering if it is possible to create this with wpf. I already know how to drag objects. There is a nice [answer in here that explains on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143072/drag-and-drop-shapes/6143220#6143220). I need the objects to be aligned though. Using the last link will just enable me to drag objects but I need them to align after I am done dragging them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways to do this, but here are a couple of ideas:

1. A custom panel with attached properties for XOffset, YOffset, and IsSnapped (default true). When the user drags an item, set IsSnapped to false and update XOffset/YOffset as they drag. The layout logic for the panel can arrange items with strong alignment (based on their XOffset/YOffset) unless IsSnapped is false, in which case they just appear at (XOffset, YOffset).
2. Using an existing drag behavior such as that provided by blend, but imposing your own coordinates on child items once they are dropped. **UPDATE**: this won't work, or would be messy, because Blend modifies the RenderTransform of dragged elements on the fly instead of updating some attached properties from which you can base your calculations.
3. Doing it predominately in view models using MVVM. That is, have properties on your view model for Top, Left, Width and Height, all of which are updated through behaviors (DragBehavior and a SizeObserver behavior). Have a parent view model expose child view models (each child represents a draggable item). Have the parent VM monitor changes to child coordinates and impose as necessary.

I'm doing something similar at the moment and have gone with #3. No regrets yet, and it's far more complicated than what you're attempting to achieve here, so you shouldn't have any blockers.

**UPDATE**: Here's my DragDrop behavior:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity.Extensions;

public static class DragDrop
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewBeginDragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "PreviewBeginDrag",
        RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent BeginDragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "BeginDrag",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewDragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "PreviewDrag",
        RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent DragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Drag",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewEndDragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "PreviewEndDrag",
        RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent EndDragEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "EndDrag",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanDragProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CanDrag",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DragDrop),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCanDragChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragInProgressProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragParentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DragParent",
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "XOffset",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty YOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "YOffset",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DragDrop));

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey isDragInProgressPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
        "IsDragInProgress",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DragDrop),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty DragPointProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DragPoint",
        typeof(Point?),
        typeof(DragDrop),
        new PropertyMetadata());

    static DragDrop()
    {
        IsDragInProgressProperty = isDragInProgressPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    }

    public static void AddPreviewBeginDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(PreviewBeginDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemovePreviewBeginDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(PreviewBeginDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void AddBeginDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(BeginDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveBeginDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(BeginDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void AddPreviewDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(PreviewDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemovePreviewDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(PreviewDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void AddDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(DragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(DragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void AddPreviewEndDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(PreviewEndDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemovePreviewEndDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(PreviewEndDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void AddEndDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.AddHandler(EndDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveEndDragHandler(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        var inputElement = dependencyObject as IInputElement;

        if (inputElement != null)
        {
            inputElement.RemoveHandler(EndDragEvent, handler);
        }
    }

    public static bool GetCanDrag(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (bool)frameworkElement.GetValue(CanDragProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCanDrag(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, bool canDrag)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(CanDragProperty, canDrag);
    }

    public static FrameworkElement GetDragParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        dependencyObject.AssertNotNull("dependencyObject");
        return dependencyObject.GetValue(DragParentProperty) as FrameworkElement;
    }

    public static void SetDragParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject, FrameworkElement dragParent)
    {
        dependencyObject.AssertNotNull("dependencyObject");
        dependencyObject.SetValue(DragParentProperty, dragParent);
    }

    public static double GetXOffset(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (double)frameworkElement.GetValue(XOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetXOffset(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double xOffset)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(XOffsetProperty, xOffset);
    }

    public static double GetYOffset(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (double)frameworkElement.GetValue(YOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetYOffset(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double yOffset)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(YOffsetProperty, yOffset);
    }

    public static bool GetIsDragInProgress(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        dependencyObject.AssertNotNull("dependencyObject");
        return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsDragInProgressProperty);
    }

    private static void SetIsDragInProgress(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool isDragInProgress)
    {
        dependencyObject.AssertNotNull("dependencyObject");
        dependencyObject.SetValue(isDragInProgressPropertyKey, isDragInProgress);
    }

    private static Point? GetDragPoint(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (Point?)frameworkElement.GetValue(DragPointProperty);
    }

    private static void SetDragPoint(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, Point? dragPoint)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(DragPointProperty, dragPoint);
    }

    private static void OnCanDragChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)dependencyObject;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            frameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonDown;
            frameworkElement.MouseMove += OnFrameworkElementMouseMove;
            frameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonUp;

            var parent = GetDragParent<FrameworkElement>(frameworkElement);

            if (parent == null)
            {
                frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(XOffsetProperty, 0d);
                frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(YOffsetProperty, 0d);
            }
            else
            {
                var pointRelativeToParent = frameworkElement.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), parent);
                frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(XOffsetProperty, pointRelativeToParent.X);
                frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(YOffsetProperty, pointRelativeToParent.Y);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            frameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonDown;
            frameworkElement.MouseMove -= OnFrameworkElementMouseMove;
            frameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonUp -= OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var parent = GetDragParent<FrameworkElement>(frameworkElement);

        if (parent == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var previewBeginDragEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(PreviewBeginDragEvent);
        frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(previewBeginDragEventArgs);

        if (previewBeginDragEventArgs.Handled)
        {
            return;
        }

        SetIsDragInProgress(frameworkElement, true);
        SetDragPoint(frameworkElement, e.GetPosition(parent));
        frameworkElement.CaptureMouse();
        frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(BeginDragEvent));
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        if (frameworkElement.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            var previewDragEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(PreviewDragEvent);
            frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(previewDragEventArgs);

            if (previewDragEventArgs.Handled)
            {
                return;
            }

            var parent = GetDragParent<FrameworkElement>(frameworkElement);

            if (parent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var currentPointRelativeToParent = e.GetPosition(parent);
            var dragPoint = GetDragPoint(frameworkElement);
            Debug.Assert(dragPoint.HasValue, "dragPoint should be set.");

            frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(XOffsetProperty, GetXOffset(frameworkElement) + (currentPointRelativeToParent.X - dragPoint.Value.X));
            frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(YOffsetProperty, GetYOffset(frameworkElement) + (currentPointRelativeToParent.Y - dragPoint.Value.Y));
            SetDragPoint(frameworkElement, currentPointRelativeToParent);
            frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DragEvent));
        }
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        if (frameworkElement.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(PreviewEndDragEvent));
            SetDragPoint(frameworkElement, null);
            frameworkElement.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            frameworkElement.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(EndDragEvent));
            SetIsDragInProgress(frameworkElement, false);
        }
    }

    private static T GetDragParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var dragParent = GetDragParent(dependencyObject) as T;

        if (dragParent != null)
        {
            return dragParent;
        }

        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        while (parent != null && !(parent is T))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        return (T)parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I guess option number two will be the easiest. The only problem is that when you drag a control how can you retrieve the coordinates when you are done using it? I think that is the only thing I need to know in order to implement your idea number 2

Comment: You shouldn't have to impose positions for layout, that is the responsibility of a Panel.

Comment: yeah but when you call the CaptureMouse() method on an object that is inside a panel the panel behaves like if it where a different control. once I am done dragging the user control it does not align it.

Comment: I recommend a different approach to takling the drag drop issue: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53

Comment: I had forgotten that the blend behavior doesn't set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top when you drag. It actually sets a RenderTransform, which is even more naff and limiting. Therefore, I think you'd be hard-pressed to use that behavior to achieve your goals. However, you could write your own, or use mine which I'll add to my post above.

Comment: Thanks this example in here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx   enables you to move controls inside a canvas changing it's top, bottom, left or right attributes. so I used that example and onmouseup I just implemented an algorithm where I will subtract it's left and top position and round that to the nearest 100, so possible values are 100, 200, 300 etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to happen dynamically, then I believe the best solution would be to create a UniformWrapPanel that derives from WrapPanel, and then override the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods. Then in the MeasureOverride method take note of the max item desired width (for horizontal alignment) and then in the ArrangeOverride method, for each line in the warp arrange process, get each item to arrange itself in a rect that is always shifted by the max item desired width.

If you know the size of the items, then I believe it will work by setting the ItemWidth and ItemHeight properties on the WrapPanel. For example:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>  
    <WrapPanel ItemWidth="150">
      <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
      <Rectangle Width="150" Height="50" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
      <Rectangle Width="20" Height="50" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
      <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
    </WrapPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

A hack solution might be to derive from WrapPanel, override the ArrangeOverride method, iterate all children and find the largest size, set the ItemWidth and ItemHeight properties, and then call the base.ArrangeOverride to do the rest of the work.